# Is there a lib for manipulating CSS on the client side in Clojurescript?

Tags: css, dynamic, clojurescript

I want to make new CSS rules on the client, for doing CSS transitions for example. Apparently jQuery has this kind of thing, but what about in the world of Clojurescript ?

I found Gaka and Garden for generating CSS on the server side like Hiccup, but what if I want to do dynamic CSS on the client side ?

Does Enlive, Dommy or any of those Clojurescript libs do that ?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [jayq](https://github.com/ibdknox/jayq)

You can do CSS manipulation to a DOM element via simple built in [css wrapper](https://github.com/ibdknox/jayq/blob/master/src/jayq/core.cljs#L83) and a Clojure map:

```
(ns myapp
  (:use [jayq.core :only [$ css inner]]))

(def $interface ($ :#interface))

(-> $interface
  (css {:background "blue"})
  (inner "Loading!"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Garden works on the client side with ClojureScript. It does virtually everything the "server side" Clojure version does with a few minor exceptions. You can use it to generate or update stylesheets in the browser if that's what you're looking for.